# What does "No file names given" mean as a make error?

Tags: makefile, c++builder

I'm trying to build a makefile and after about 5 seconds, I get this error: "No files names given".  what does it mean and how do I fix it?

```
[exec] Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland
[exec] Error E2266: No file names given
[exec] ** error 1 ** deleting paslib.lib
```

This is being run from a BPG file with the options "-B" and -"fproject.bpg".

I'm relatively new to makefiles so I'm unsure of how to make Make pass files to the compiler. From my understanding, I call make with a make file consisting of various projects. Make file takes each project, creates another makefiles (with bpr2mak) and then compiles it (with bcc32).  Is this correct?  If it is, then make should pass the compiler the file name to build.  From looking at my output, the project successfully makes a make file, but the compiler fails.

Comment: It would be best if you left a snipped of the offending makefile rule here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the actual problem is with bcc32.exe, not make.  The problem is discussed here:
[Why can't the Borland C++ Builder 5 command line compiler find my files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489308/why-cant-the-borland-c-builder-5-command-line-compiler-find-my-files)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're calling the Borland C++ compiler command without passing it any file names to compile. Perhaps a Make variable that is supposed to contain the C++ file names is empty, misspelled, etc.