# Why can't the Borland C++ Builder 5 command line compiler find my files?

Tags: command-line, c++builder

I have a bcb5 project group that I am trying to compile with make.exe.  Make seems to run fine and generates a call to bcc32.exe, but that fails.  Here is the call to bcc32.exe followed by the error.

```
M:\projects\Project>"D:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder5\Bin\bcc32.exe" -Od
-H=.\obj_files\vcl50.csm -Hc -Vx -Ve -X- -a8 -5 -b- -k- -vi -c -tW   -tWM -w
-par -IP:\b5\crc32\ISC\;Query;Z:\Bin\;Help;pas;D:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\bin\
..\include;D:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~1\bin\..\include\vcl;DataCenter;"P:\b5\Gif
Image\" -D;NO_STRICT;_RTLDLL -nobj_files\ help\chelp.cpp

Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland

Error E2266: No file names given
```

It appears to me that the file is obviously 'chelp.cpp'.  What's wrong here?

Comment: Are you compiling, linking, or running?  What command is being run? Some more details would be appreciated.

Comment: The command is calling bcc32, which is a compiler.  The above command compiles the file (chelp.cpp) and then calls the linker to link required files as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the idea, strager.  It was close, but the actual problem is the set of quotes around P:\bg\Gif Image.  Changing them to single quotes fixes the problem.

I believe this can be also be solved with FixMake: http://www.grassvalleysoftware.com/. FixMake takes a makefile and cleans up things such as trailing backslashes and escaped quotations.

Comment: Please move this into your original question, so it's clear that you've solved your original issue and you are looking for the solution to another similar issue.

Comment: It is also possible to fix this error when modifying the .bpr file first, for example using sed:  `sed -e "/\\\&quot;/s//\&quot;/g" project.bpr > project.bpr.new`

Answer (score 1):

A guess is that `-nobj_files\` (near the end of the command) is causing the next space to be excaped.  Try excaping the `\` or removing it.